# Difference between OneToMany and ManyToMany unidirectional relationships

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Is there difference because I don't see one. How the model knows that there are many to many if there is not bidirectional relationship. Lets say that user have phones and phone can be to multiple users. If there is unidirectional relationship described in User entity that is ManyToMany what makes it more different about the Phone entity from the OneToMany unidirectional relationship again desribed in User.

Is it necessary to make the exact description of the relationships so that everything to work as expected. I had described OneToMany relationships as OneToOne and the model still worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A unidirectional OneToMany can use join columns or a join table.  If it is join columns, then there is a foreign key in the target entity that can only reference a single entity.  If you choose a join table, then DDL can be generated such that constraints are added to make the foreign keys to the target entity unique, enforcing a strict 1:M relationship.  But they don't have to.  From a JPA perspective, using a join table on a OneToMany gives it pretty much exactly the same behavior as a ManyToMany.

As for mapping a OneToMany as a OneToOne - it depends on what you mean.  If your OneToMany relation was based on a foreign key existing in the target entity's table, then it is logically a OneToOne in the database going the other way.  The only difference is that when building your source entity, JPA will only expect a single target entity when building the relationship.  So if that foreign key in the target is not unique (ie there are many that would match), only the first is likely to be pulled up and placed in the relationship - so the relationship state will not match the actual database data.  This will cause you problems when you try to manipulate the relationship directly or merge from other contexts since it could have been populated differently.

Comment: I didn't know that unidirectional relationship is possible without join table and I searched and found this link: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany#Undirectional_OneToMany.2C_No_Inverse_ManyToOne.2C_No_Join_Table_.28JPA_2.0_ONLY.29
So my question was only about the case with Join table. Thank you for the answer